# How to use regex for field validation on whole string?

Tags: regex

I've been working for many hours trying to do a "simple thing": use a regex to validate a text field.

I need to make sure of:

1- Only use (a-z), (A-Z) and (0-9) values
2- Add a SINGLE wildcard only at the end.

Ex.

***Match***

> MICHE*

***Match***

> JAMES

***No match***

> MICHE**

***No match***

> MIC_HEAL*

I have this regex till now:

> [a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+.\z*?

The problem is it still matches when I introduce an invalid character as long as I have a matching sub-string [See my REGEX](http://rubular.com/r/TUh6miAnia)

What can I do to force a match on the whole string? What am I missing?

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) to only match the whole string:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+.\z*?$
```

(If you have a multiline input you can also use `\A` and `\z` - start and end of string)

On a second look, I don't understand the end of your regex: `.` (anything) `\z` `*` `?` (end of string, zero or more times, zero or one time). This regex will match something like:

```
Ikdflfdf&
```

Is that correct? If you only want the character `*`, you should use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+\*?$
```

Also, as Robbie pointed out, you're including spaces and the `-` in your list of accepted characters. If you only want letters and digits, a shortcut would be using `\w` (word characters):

```
^\w+\*$
```

However, depending on whether the matcher is Unicode-aware or not, `\w` will also match non-ASCII letters and digits, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thx! My regex is my lame attempt to include "*" at the end as option. And yes, I need spaces and dashes.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*?$
```

^ string start

$ string end

* is meta character so it should be escaped like `\*` to use it as a letter

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need `^` at the begining and `$` at the end

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+.\*?$
```

Also, you don't need the `\z`

Also, you haven't mentioned that you want to allow spaces and dashes `-` but you have included them in your allowed character set.